# Pills or what to do when you are emotional

Tags: psychosomatic-illness

I am emotional guy  and I cant sleep at night.What can i do to overcome this? I have take a hot shower and after i went to bed but my thoughts didnt left me to slept.Always the same thing i cant slept.I have anger and many things.I have looked my life with different aspect of view but it failed once again.I havent the courage anymore.What can i do to stop feeling stop beeing emotional especial with the other woman.I cant control it anymore.I went to psychologie not helped me with this.

Comment: Sorry, but site rules prohibit us from offering personal medical advice.